# How do I configure checkpoint remove in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm sry to speck english not well

job node can delete old checkpoints. but, task node can't

I already setted retain-num.

and I try to use NFS mount but not operating.

so What should I do?

Comment: I get Permission denied in Job Manager Logs when using NFS mount

Comment: If it's an permission issue, could you maybe attach a `ls -la` of that folder? It could be that someone added files with different permissions/owner to these subdirectories in the meantime.